# Joining data that exists in two tables and aggregating non joined data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, join

I have two Tables

```
Name    | ID      | 
--------+---------+
A       | 3       | 
A       | 5       | 
B       | 1       | 



 ID     | Count   | 
--------+---------+
1       | 10      | 
2       | 50      | 
3       | 15      | 
6       | 20      |
```

I want to produce something which joins the ID of these two tables as well as aggregating the results of the non-matching entries

```
Name    | ID      | Count
--------+---------+----------
A       | 3       | 15
A       | 5       | 0 *//(doesn't exists)*
A       | others  | 80 *//(10 (ID 1) + 50 (ID 2) + 20 (ID 6))*
B       | 1       | 10
B       | others  | 85 *//(50 (ID 2) + 15 (ID 3) + 20 (ID 6))*
```

Till now I can get the matched items but not able to get the non matching aggregates.

I feel that doing an `except` on each list of IDs and aggregating the non matching ones is not an elegant solution.

Would like to find a more elegant solution to the problem.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that I am using `SQL server`.
The oracle solution would not be of any use in my scenario but will help in a similar scenario for Oracle users.

Comment: You can do it with full outer join in case of oracle and sql server. In case of mysql left join union right join will do it. what dbms are you using.

Comment: @Mani I don't think this is doable with a single query, parts of his result need to be aggregated while other parts - not aggregated.

Comment: @SvetoslavTsolov. It seems he needs grouping  for entire result. Not partial. sum(count) with group by name, id. Where name and id are coalesced based on join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LINQ solution is this:

```
from n in Names
join c in Counts on n.ID equals c.ID into outer
select new { n.Name, 
             ID = outer.Count() > 1 ? "others" : n.ID.ToString(),
             Sum = ((int?)outer.Sum(x => x.Count)) ?? 0 }
```

It does the equivalent of an outer join, but also has some trickery to translate a `null` to `0`. In linq-to-sql this nicely translates into SQL. And because it is translated into SQL `outer.Count()` does not throw an exception when `outer` is `null`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is getting only the matched results. I do not think this is doing an outer join.

Comment: @user2427375 Are you sure? `join ... into` is the equivalent of `GroupJoin()`, which is the equivalent of outer join. In a similar query I get results for all "Names", including the ones without "Counts".

Answer (score 1):

How about this:
Get the matched items and do a union with a second query.
The second query would select name, 'others', sum(count) and would group on name where id is not in the ids from the first table (you can check that with a subquery).

I can type it out if you want to, you look like you know what you are doing and just need a general idea about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In case of oracle use nvl. sql server ifnull() and mysql isnull() with union of left and right outer instead of full outer

```
select name, id, sum(cnt) from
(
select name, nvl(to_char(a.id), 'others') id, nvl(b.count,0) cnt 
from table1 a 
     full outer join 
     table2 b on a.id = b.id)
group by name, id
```